# Handle the content of a txt file using windows API

Tags: c++, windows, file, buffer, readfile

I use the fragment of code as follows to get the contents of a text file. However the buffer `buff` at the end has only the number 8 at one place and nothing else. The file being opened has the word "Project" as the only content. How can I handle (i.e. print) the content or the result I should receive? What is wrong with the following code:

```
        TCHAR buff[20];
        DWORD dwNumRead;
        CString finalPath = path + L"\\" + fileName.c_str();
        HANDLE hfile=CreateFile(finalPath ,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

        if(ReadFile(hfile,buff,20,&dwNumRead,NULL))
        {
            CString temp;
            temp.Format(L"%s",&buff[0]);
            ATLTRACE(L"Success %s", temp);
        }
        CloseHandle(hfile);
```

Comment: Are you compiling with Unicode or Multi-byte character set?  If you're compiling multi-byte and format with `L"%s"`, then the first character would have a trailing `0`, which would be treated like a terminating-null in multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that you are trying to print the MFC CString which is composed of wide character with %s macro. You need the %S macro to print the wide character.

This works :

```
    char buff[20] = "";
    DWORD dwNumRead;
    CString finalPath = path + L"\\" + fileName.c_str();;
    HANDLE hfile=CreateFile(finalPath ,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if(ReadFile(hfile,buff,20,&dwNumRead,NULL))
    {
        CString temp = buff;
        ATLTRACE("Success %S", temp);
    }
    CloseHandle(hfile);
```

Otherwise, compile your program in unicode with the following extra C++ defs.
UNICODE,_UNICODE

Comment: OK, it works so. The problem was at the first line, namely it cannot work by TCHAR[], although it is commonly suggested this way.

Comment: TCHAR works too. You have to compile your program with UNICODE macros